# How to install tinymce package with composer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce, composer-php, laravel-5

I am trying to use tinymce with Laravel 5.2.

Till now I am done with `composer require tinymce/tinymce` and `composer update`.

The package got installed in `vendor` directory with the directory name `tinymce`.

What are the next steps ? I guess we have to add PackageServiceProvider in `app/config/app.php` but how ?

Thanks in advance,

Sambhav

Answer (score 0):

I found this lib of tinymce for laravel. you can try it.

https://github.com/ktquez/laravel-tinymce

Comment: I saw it when I was trying to search for the answers but passed it without looking much. Now when I am seeing it looks good to me I will try to use it and will get back in case of any questions. Thanks for the help.

- Sambhav